Equation of a line segment (passing through origin) in polar form
I know the equation for a line (not passing through origin) is $r = r_0\cdot sec(\theta - \phi)$
But that equation just doesn't hold for line passing through origin. If we have another parameter (not $\theta$), say, $a$ then $f(r,a)$ is just $r = a$. It's a line with slope $\frac{\pi}{4}$
To obtain a line with some arbitrary slope, we can just multiply $a$ with $tan(p)$. So, the equation of line would be $r = a\cdot tan(p)$. But I couldn't find out what conditions to that line equation can make it a line segment. Is there some other way to find out the equation of a line segment?
The equation $r = a\cdot tan(p)$ here is just like $y = m\cdot x$. It doesn't seem that $r = a\cdot tan(p)$ is a polar equation but it worked when I tried this in desmos.
Question similar to this:
What would the equation of diameter of a circle centered at origin be?

A ray through the origin is given by $\theta=\theta_0$. You can only obtain a segment by imposing inequalities $a\le r\le b$.

@Ted Shifrin I'm actually trying to plot it in desmos. I've tried putting these $-n\le a\le n$ and $-n\le a\cdot tan(p)\le n$ so that the length is $2n$ but these inequalities just bound the line to be in $[-n,n]$.

I honestly do not follow your parameter $a$ at all. I read polar in the title and went with that.

@TedShifrin would you please reconsider my question? I edited it.

You need $\theta=c$ for any $c$, and then the inequality $-a\le r\le a$.
